# Kendo Grid align column same top offset

Tags: javascript, css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a problem and I cannot find solution to it.

I have KendoUI Grid which has different row height - like in this example
http://jsfiddle.net/Sbb5Z/2/

I tried with special class in column but nothing helps

```
{
    attributes: {
    "class": "paddingTopZero"
  },
}
```

where 3rd row is bigger than other (2 rows in 4th column).

I would like to achive, that data in this row would have all same top offset - so 1., 2., 3. 5. and 6th column in this row wouldn't be positioned in the middle of the row but on the same line ans 4th row - same top padding.

Is there and way to achive that? I really wound't like to correct this paddings manually - I'm sure grid has this options but I just cannot find it.

Tnx for and idea with this

Comment: Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Sbb5Z/1894/) ?

Comment: Yes exactly like that. Tnx.

Comment: Can you accept my answer, if it is right ?

Answer (score 5):

Use CSS [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) property:

```
vertical-align: top
```

You can use as you tried, declaring it in a class and define in column's [`attribute`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.attributes) property. Or you can set it as global to any grid you have with:

```
.k-grid tbody tr td 
{
    vertical-align: top
}
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sbb5Z/1894/)**</kbd>